How to re-try fetching data using google firestore pagination Flutter
I'm using flutter to build my mobile app and I'm using google firestore to store all of my data. I have managed to create a function to store my data and fetch the data, I also managed to create a filter button to show certain part of my data.
The problem is, when I filter my data sometimes we need to register the query index on firebase. So sometimes when the query index is not registered, it will show error message and asked the user to try again.
I wanted to change the interface of the error massage and I managed to do that by using firstPageErrorIndicatorBuilder
But I also want to keep the 'try again' button and it's functionality.
What's the code to 'try again' in firestore pagination ? I can't find it in the documentation

There is nothing special you can do to retry a query in Firestore using the Firestore APIs.  Just execute the same query code again every time you want to perform the query.  It sounds you actually need to write some other unrelated application logic to make your app do that query again on demand.  Since you haven't shared with us your existing code, it's going to hard for someone to make a recommendation on that.  I suggest rewriting your question to be more clear what you're trying to do along with the code you have now that doesn't work the way you expect.
